# How can I change the variable name in a for loop using for loop variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, variables

I have these variables with their assigned values. And I want to assign a same number (here 100) to all of them with a for loop. However I do not know how. I want the ai to change with the i  in the for loop.

```
a1=2;
a2=4;
a3=12;
a4=1;
for i=1:4
ai=100
end
```

Comment: [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval)

Comment: ***NO***. Never create dynamic variables in the first place. Use a matrix to store all these values and iterate over its indices if a for loop is needed. However in this case, you do not need a loop. Just set all elements to a specific value with matrix indexing.